# csquotes doesn't interact with polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia, csquotes

According to the `csquotes` package, "the style of all quotation marks will be
adapted to the current language" if `babel` or `polyglossia` is loaded. For English the default style is `quotes`, and for Norwegian the default is `guillemets`. But with the following code both quotes are with `quotes`, even though the Norwegian quote is embedded in a `norsk` environment. What is missing here in order to get the default guillemets for quotes in a Norwegian environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{norsk}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

    \enquote{This is English}.

\begin{norsk}
    \enquote{Dette er norsk}.
\end{norsk}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that the quotes adapts continuously to the language you need the `autostyle=true` option (the default is tryonce):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{norsk}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

    \enquote{This is English}.

\begin{norsk}
    \enquote{Dette er norsk}.
\end{norsk}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Right! I misinterpreted what `tryonce` meant when I read the manual.